# Command-line ssh address book app

Tags: beginner, console, go, yaml, ssh

I'm trying to learn a bit about Golang and decided to try out building an SSH address book command-line app. I used a YAML library to serialize and store data in a configuration file. The app has a few command-line options to view, delete, make, and run SSH address entries. It also runs the `ssh` command given an entry name and no arguments.

I'm looking for some criticism on things I should improve.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

// Sturct that contains the list of all SSHEntry structs
type EntriesList struct {
    SSHEntries []SSHEntry `yaml:"sshentries"`
}

// Struct that holds the name of the SSHCmd entry and the SSHCmd struct itself
type SSHEntry struct {
    Name    string `yaml:"name"`
    Command SSHCmd `yaml:"command"`
}

// Struct that contains the Address, Port number, and Username for executing ssh commands
type SSHCmd struct {
    Addr  string `yaml:"addr"`
    Port  int    `yaml:"port"`
    Uname string `yaml:"uname"`
}

func main() {
    MAKE := flag.Bool("make", false, "Specify whether you want to make a new entry")
    CONF := flag.String("conf", "/misc/sshbook-g/sshbook.yml", "Specify location of configuration file")
    VIEW := flag.Bool("view", false, "View previous entries")
    CLEAN := flag.Bool("clean", false, "Delete all stored entries")
    CHECK := flag.String("check", "", "Check for entry stored in yaml file by entry name")
    DELETE := flag.Bool("delete", false, "Delete an entry")

    flag.Parse()
    if flag.NFlag() > 0 {
        if *MAKE {
            entries := readConf(*CONF)
            addEntry(entries)
            writeEntries(entries, *CONF)
        } else if *VIEW {
            viewEntries(*CONF)
        } else if *CLEAN {
            cleanEntries(*CONF)
        } else if len(*CHECK) > 0 {
            entries := readConf(*CONF)
            if searchEntriesList(entries, *CHECK) != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s is available\n", *CHECK)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%s is not available\n", *CHECK)
            }
        } else if *DELETE {
            entries := readConf(*CONF)
            deleteAnEntry(entries, *CONF)
        }
        return
    }

    if len(os.Args) < 1 {
        panic("Need an argument")
    }
    entries := readConf(*CONF)
    entry_name := os.Args[1]
    runnable_entry := searchEntriesList(entries, entry_name)
    if runnable_entry != nil {
        run(runnable_entry.Command)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("That entry is not available")
    }
}

// Allows a user to delete an entry, First prints out the whole list 
// and has the user to specify the name of the entry to be deleted
func deleteAnEntry(entries *EntriesList, CONF string) {
    viewEntries(CONF)
    fmt.Println("Enter the name of the entry you wish to delete:")
    var answer string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &answer)
    toDelete := searchEntriesListIndex(entries, answer)
    if toDelete == -1 {
        fmt.Println("Cannot find that entry")
        return
    }
    entries.SSHEntries = append(entries.SSHEntries[:toDelete], entries.SSHEntries[toDelete+1:]...)
    writeEntries(entries, CONF)
}

// Calls makeEntry to create a new SSHEntry struct and adds it to the master list of current entries.
func addEntry(entries *EntriesList) {
    newEntry := makeEntry()
    entries.SSHEntries = append(entries.SSHEntries, *newEntry)
}

// Creates a new struct via prompting user for imformation about ssh command they wish to enter
// Returns pointer to new SSHEntry struct
func makeEntry() (entry *SSHEntry) {
    var uname, addr, entryName string
    var port int
    port = -1
    fmt.Println("Enter the data for a new entry")
    fmt.Println("Enter the username: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &uname)
    fmt.Println("Enter the port number: ")
    fmt.Println("(Leave empty for default port)")
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &port)
    fmt.Println("Enter the address: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &addr)
    fmt.Println("Enter the entry name you would like to use: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &entryName)
    // If port is unchanged, then the user picked the default option
    if port < 0 {
        port = 22
    }
    return &SSHEntry{entryName, SSHCmd{addr, port, uname}}
}

// Generic error checking function
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil && e != io.EOF {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
}

// Serializes entries list and writes it to the configuration file using ioutil's WriteFile function
func writeEntries(entries *EntriesList, CONF string) {
    bodyBytes, err := yaml.Marshal(entries)
    check(err)
    ioutil.WriteFile(CONF, bodyBytes, 0644)
    check(err)
}

// Deletes entry list by writing an empyt byte[] to the configuration file
func cleanEntries(CONF string) {
    var answer string
    fmt.Println("This will clean out all the currently stored entries. Are you sure? y/n")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &answer)
    if answer != "y" {
        return
    }
    ioutil.WriteFile(CONF, []byte(""), 0644)
}

// Prints entries as yaml data by running the shell command `cat` on the configuratoin file and printing it's output.
func viewEntries(CONF string) {
    catCmd := exec.Command("cat", CONF)
    output, err := catCmd.Output()
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}

// Performs linear search on entries list for a given name.
// Returns nil if no entry names match searchString.
func searchEntriesList(entries *EntriesList, searchString string) *SSHEntry {
    for i := 0; i < len(entries.SSHEntries); i += 1 {
        if entries.SSHEntries[i].Name == searchString {
            return &entries.SSHEntries[i]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Identical to searchEntriesList but returns index in entries list rather than struct pointer.
// returns -1 if no results are found.
func searchEntriesListIndex(entries *EntriesList, searchString string) int {
    for i := 0; i < len(entries.SSHEntries); i += 1 {
        if entries.SSHEntries[i].Name == searchString {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

// Reads configuration file and deserializes yaml data into native structs.
// Returns pointer to list of all entries.
func readConf(CONF string) *EntriesList {
    confiFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(CONF)
    check(err)
    var entries EntriesList
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(confiFile, &entries)
    check(err)
    return &entries
}

// Runs the ssh command using the given SSHCmd struct to gather necessary data.
// Currently only supports using passwords as authentication methods.
// Waits for session to end then returns
func run(command SSHCmd) error {
    password := askForPassword()
    config := ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: command.Uname,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(password)},
    }
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", command.Addr, command.Port), &config)
    check(err)
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    check(err)
    defer session.Close()
    session.Stdout = os.Stdout
    session.Stderr = os.Stderr
    session.Stdin = os.Stdin

    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,
        ssh.ECHOCTL:       0,
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400,
    }
    if err = session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes); err != nil {
        check(err)
    }
    if err = session.Shell(); err != nil {
        check(err)
    }

    return session.Wait()
}

// Asks for password
// Returns password as string
func askForPassword() string {
    fmt.Println("Enter your password:")
    pwbytes, err := terminal.ReadPassword(0)
    check(err)
    return string(pwbytes)
}
```